# Is there any relationship between the Faro Plague and the AI rights campaigners?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

Throughout Horizon Zero Dawn there are scattered references to AI rights campaigners in various logs and information dumps.

Do these campaigners have any connection to the Faro Plague, or are they merely included to add some color to the pre plague world.

It seems unusual to me that there are people talking about hacking, and about freeing AI from human dominance, at the same time as a robot revolution is going on, and yet I haven't found any in game text where somebody either connects the two or denies that one is related to the other.

Comment: Probably just add "pre-plague color". The Faro Plague was an anomaly - if it took world-renown engineers to create an AI that would crack the Faro's robots security protocols after a century of *brute force*, I doubt your average campaigners/activist would be able to cause the Faro Plague (if that's what you're asking)

Comment: The loss of control of the robots is always referred to as a "glitch" which suggests a programming error to me. I don't think there are any datapoints in Zero Dawn (or Forbidden West) that give any more details.

Comment: It has nothing to do, imho. Maybe we'll learn something more in the third chapter.